# Wkwebview doesn't react to youtube-links

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm currently wrapping a website in a native tabBar, and it handles navigation using *didCommitNavigation/didFinishNavigation* and *didStartProvisionalNavigation/didFailProvisionalNavigation* to change tabs according to what links are clicked. This works just fine when it comes to links that are within the domain of the website, but there seems to be no reaction at all from the webview when clicking a Youtube-link.

[I thought it might have to do with my security settings, but it seems like it doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL7PV.png)

Here is my main viewcontroller, which is the one and only viewcontroller of the project:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var noConnectionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!
@IBOutlet weak var statusImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewForWeb: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var retryButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

let statusColors: [UIColor] = UIColor.getStatusColors()

var currentIndex: Int = 0

var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, viewForWeb.frame.size.width, viewForWeb.frame.size.height))

    viewForWeb.addSubview(webView)
    webView.scrollView.delegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self


    loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
    tabBar.delegate = self

    tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.tabBarBackgroundColor()
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.iconColor()
    for item in tabBar.items! {
        item.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -3)
        item.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.iconColor()], forState:.Normal)
        item.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.iconColor()], forState:.Selected)
    }
    tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "news-tab")
    tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![0]

    statusImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.newsColor()

    webView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: startURLs[0]))
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func retryConnection(sender: AnyObject) {
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: failedNavigationURL))
    noConnectionLabel.hidden = true
    retryButton.hidden = true
    loadingIndicator.hidden = false

}


func webView(webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print(webView.URL!)
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didCommitNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print(webView.URL!)
    for view in views {
        if webView.URL!.absoluteString.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(view) != nil {
            tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "\((view as NSString).substringToIndex(view.characters.count - 1))-tab")!
            if tabBar.selectedItem != tabBar.items![views.indexOf(view)!] {
                currentIndex = views.indexOf(view)!
                tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![views.indexOf(view)!]
                statusImage.backgroundColor = statusColors[tabBar.items!.indexOf(tabBar.selectedItem!)!]
                viewForWeb.hidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
    statusImage.backgroundColor = statusColors[tabBar.items!.indexOf(tabBar.selectedItem!)!]
    loadingIndicator.hidden = true
    noConnectionLabel.hidden = true
    retryButton.hidden = true
    viewForWeb.hidden = false
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
    failedNavigationURL = NSURL(string: error.userInfo[NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]! as! NSString as String)!
    statusImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    viewForWeb.hidden = true
    noConnectionLabel.hidden = false
    retryButton.hidden = false
    loadingIndicator.hidden = true
}


func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

    let indexOfItem = tabBar.items!.indexOf(item)!

    if indexOfItem != currentIndex {
        tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "\(item.title!.lowercaseString)-tab")
        statusImage.backgroundColor = statusColors[indexOfItem]
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.open();document.close()", completionHandler: nil)
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: startURLs[indexOfItem]))
        currentIndex = indexOfItem
        loadingIndicator.hidden = false
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
        viewForWeb.hidden = true
    }
}

func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x>0 || scrollView.contentOffset.x<0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
    }
}
```

I omitted some arrays for anonymity, but I think it's still readable. To clarify, the print()s only print URLs that are within the domain of the website, and nothing when clicking Yotube-links.

Comment: I put your code into my XCode and Youtube links are working well. Have you got any other hint to reproduce your issue better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I have also faced the same problem. It's happening because wkwebview delegates don't return any callback in in-page javascript operation, what is actually happening in the case of youtube.

However, you can solve it using KV Observer.

Write this code in your viewDidLoad or any initialization function:

```
webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: .new, context: nil)
```

Get callback in this function:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) 
  {
    if keyPath! == "URL" {
      getYourVideoURL = (webView.url?.absoluteString)!
    }
  }
```

Remember to remove observer in viewDidDisappear or where ever you want to stop getting callbacks.

Comment: Thanks @saumyadip This is the simplest example I've found of how to do this correctly.